# Ubuntu 12.04 Libreoffice crashing when typing malayalam in IBus

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, ibus

Libreoffice keeps crashing when typing Malayalam inscript with IBus. Especially when I press the keys "a" and "x" one by one.

Below the terminal output when I open the Libreoffice Writer via terminal.

```
sree@ubuntucafe:~$ lowriter 
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0a205cd8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73e42)[0xb74cce42]
/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.48(uprv_free_48+0x48)[0xb5708cd8]
/usr/lib/libicule.so.48(_ZN6icu_4814LEGlyphStorage5resetEv+0x82)[0xb554b042]
/usr/lib/libicule.so.48(_ZN6icu_4812LayoutEngine5resetEv+0x1e)[0xb553eb8e]
/usr/lib/libicule.so.48(_ZN6icu_4820OpenTypeLayoutEngine5resetEv+0x1b)[0xb553bf2b]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(+0x386fc2)[0xb619ffc2]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(_ZN16ServerFontLayout10LayoutTextER14ImplLayoutArgs+0x4c)[0xb61a0b5c]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(+0x1d4e21)[0xb5fede21]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(_ZNK12OutputDevice12GetTextArrayERK6StringPltt+0xb6)[0xb5fee956]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(_ZNK12OutputDevice12GetTextWidthERK6Stringtt+0x3d)[0xb5feeaad]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x4ec6de)[0xab8316de]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x503e8d)[0xab848e8d]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x483bd6)[0xab7c8bd6]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x48142a)[0xab7c642a]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x4b46fe)[0xab7f96fe]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x495d35)[0xab7dad35]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x497287)[0xab7dc287]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x477e57)[0xab7bce57]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x47a51e)[0xab7bf51e]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x47b24b)[0xab7c024b]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x47bb23)[0xab7c0b23]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x3b73d8)[0xab6fc3d8]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x3b4589)[0xab6f9589]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x3e6363)[0xab72b363]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x3e65c4)[0xab72b5c4]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x3e9cf8)[0xab72ecf8]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(_ZN9ViewShell13ImplEndActionEh+0x55b)[0xab9c74db]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(_ZN11SwCrsrShell9EndActionEh+0x28b)[0xab53ad3b]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(_ZN11SwEditShell12EndAllActionEv+0x5f)[0xab690e1f]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(_ZN11SwEditShell19SetExtTextInputDataERK23CommandExtTextInputData+0x11d)[0xab67d4ad]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../program/libswlo.so(+0x837483)[0xabb7c483]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(+0x34ef01)[0xb6167f01]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvcllo.so(+0x352e39)[0xb616be39]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvclplug_gtklo.so(+0x444ac)[0xb25694ac]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRINGv+0x63)[0xb1f850a3]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xd727)[0xb1f82727]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0x449)[0xb1f9ba29]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_by_name+0x44f)[0xb1f9c8af]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x11d6dd)[0xb21da6dd]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRINGv+0x63)[0xb1f850a3]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xd727)[0xb1f82727]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0x449)[0xb1f9ba29]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x33)[0xb1f9c453]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so(+0x309f)[0xae63209f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv+0x60)[0xb1f85690]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xd727)[0xb1f82727]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0x449)[0xb1f9ba29]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x33)[0xb1f9c453]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0(+0x1655c)[0xae5e455c]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_SYSV+0x1a)[0xb1c2735a]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x6f)[0xb1c2708f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_generic+0x1c4)[0xb1f82d94]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0xc2fd)[0xb1f812fd]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x184)[0xb1f82484]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x1f70d)[0xb1f9470d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xcfc)[0xb1f9c2dc]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x33)[0xb1f9c453]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0xcb407)[0xb1d63407]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0xb92f6)[0xb1d512f6]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x44740)[0xb1ec0740]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x17a)[0xb1ec2cda]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x470e5)[0xb1ec30e5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x41)[0xb1ec31c1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201758     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:07 201758     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 201758     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
093d8000-0a23c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
aa67d000-aa7e4000 r--s 00000000 08:07 9026       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf
aa7e4000-aa873000 r--s 00000000 08:07 9022       /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf
aa873000-aa87a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201890     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmcnttype.so
aa87a000-aa87b000 r--p 00006000 08:07 201890     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmcnttype.so
aa87b000-aa87c000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 201890     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmcnttype.so
aa87c000-aa87d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
aa87d000-ab08d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
ab08d000-ab0a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201655     /usr/lib/ure/lib/introspection.uno.so
ab0a9000-ab0aa000 ---p 0001c000 08:07 201655     /usr/lib/ure/lib/introspection.uno.so
ab0aa000-ab0ab000 r--p 0001c000 08:07 201655     /usr/lib/ure/lib/introspection.uno.so
ab0ab000-ab0ac000 rw-p 0001d000 08:07 201655     /usr/lib/ure/lib/introspection.uno.so
ab0ac000-ab118000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201912     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libunoxmllo.so
ab118000-ab120000 r--p 0006b000 08:07 201912     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libunoxmllo.so
ab120000-ab121000 rw-p 00073000 08:07 201912     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libunoxmllo.so
ab121000-ab139000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201819     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libhelplinkerlo.so
ab139000-ab13a000 r--p 00017000 08:07 201819     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libhelplinkerlo.so
ab13a000-ab13b000 rw-p 00018000 08:07 201819     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libhelplinkerlo.so
ab13b000-ab1e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 201862     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libdeployment.so
ab1e6000-ab1ec000 r--p 000ab000 08:07 201862     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libdeployment.so
ab1ec000-ab1ed000 rw-p 000b1000 08:07 201862     /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libdeployment.so
```

Kernel version

```
sree@ubuntucafe:~$ uname -r
3.2.0-23-generic-pae
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was fixed in [Libreoffice 4.0](http://www.libreoffice.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to upgrade Ubuntu to 12.10 or LibreOffice to a newer version? There was a bug filed for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1023426, which adds it's fixed in LO 3.5.X. I'm running LO 3.6.2.2 in 12.10, tried it just now, and had no trouble with all 4 Malayam input methods in ibus.

Comment: Updated to LibreOffice 3.6 . But same problem exist.